# How to handle async forEach, pass results into database and then render complete data set

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'd like to:

1. Make a call to an API resource
2. Get back an array of records - [arr]
3. forEach over [arr] and perform some function  - another aysnc call to an API
4. For each iteration, create an object that has elements of the original API call, and the subsequent call for each item
5. Save each object instance generated to Mongo
6. At the end of all required save operations, call the complete collection from Mongo
7. res.render that collection

I have code that looks like this:

```
  //First API call to get [arr]
  const results = await getlist();
  //Iterate over [arr] and perform a request on each item 
  _.forEach(results, async function (result) {

  //Seconday request for each item in [arr]
  const record = await item(result.id).fetch();

  //Combined doc from original result and secondary call for record
  let doc = new DocModel({
    item1: result.id,
    item2: record.something,
    
  });
  //Save doc
  const saveDoc = doc.save();

  });

//Call for all docs
const allItems = await DocModel.find();

 //Render all docs
 res.render(`aView`, {
   recordings: allItems,
 });
```

The problem I am facing is that the render executes before the forEach has completed / has populated Mongo.

To try and work around this, I have tried to wrap the forEach block in a promise, and then .then res.render, but this seemed to have no effect.

What is the solution to ensure all function calls have completed before the render occurs?

Comment: replace forEach with `for in` or `for of`

Comment: Thanks @AbishekKumar - Are you able to outline why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I place two marks in following code. And i deleted the `_.forEach` function

mark1: Use normal for-loop to do it
mark2: use await here

```js
//First API call to get [arr]
const results = await getlist();

// ########## mark1 ########## : Use normal for-loop to do it
for (const result of results) {
    //Seconday request for each item in [arr]
    const record = await item(result.id).fetch();

    //Combined doc from original result and secondary call for record
    let doc = new DocModel({
        item1: result.id,
        item2: record.something,

    });
    // ########## mark2 ########## : use await here 
    //Save doc
    const saveDoc = await doc.save();
}

//Call for all docs
const allItems = await DocModel.find();

//Render all docs
res.render(`aView`, {
    recordings: allItems,
});
```

Comment: Great answer thank you, with detail. I am wondering why _.forEach can't be used here - What's the concept I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `async await` inside `forEach`. Instead you need to use `for...of` loop.

Another best solution is to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thank you @william - Could you outline why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
await Promise.all(_.map(results,async result => {
   ... existing code
});
```